# Can the JsonProperty required value be conditional?

Tags: java, json, fasterxml

Is it possible to have the @JsonProperty required dynamically set or set at call?

The reason behind this...
I'm generating json files which describes a schema and defines

- What are the required fields for a ***new*** item
- What are the required fields for an ***update*** to an item.

So, a creation requires only foo

and an update requires foo and bar

Can I make things so I can pass in something to say **bar** is now required?

or would I need to duplicate this code in order to have different settings for JsonProperty?

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)

public class Bean {

    @JsonProperty(value="foo", required=false)
    private FooProperty fooProperty;

    @JsonProperty(value="bar", required=false)
    private BarProperty barProperty;

    //
    public FooProperty getFooProperty() { return fooProperty; }

    public void setFooProperty(FooProperty argFooProperty) {
        this.fooProperty = argFooProperty
    }


    public BarProperty getBarProperty() { return barProperty; }

    public void setFooProperty(BarProperty argBarProperty) {
        this.barProperty = argBarProperty
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain your case a bit elaborately ?

Comment: Added more details.

Comment: is it for serialization/deserialization? have you looked at custom serializer? Is using `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonAnySetter` a viable option for you?

Comment: I'll look into the JsonAnyGetter and JsonAnySetter right now and see where that leads me. This is all new to me. Thanks

Comment: Yes the code is for serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve this issue in couple of ways. First one would be as `Franjavi` suggested you could use a mixin.

Have a mixin class which will mark your `foo` as one of the ignored properties. In your main class mark both the fiends required and you can inject this mixin whenever this is an option field.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("foo")
public abstract class mixinClass {

}
```

You configure your mixin into your mapper as follows.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(Bean.class, mixinClass.class);
```

This is not always a working option whenever you are getting this response from a third party API where you might be serializing/deserializing using the default jackson mapper which are provided by them like Resttemplate.

In this case, instead of having the `foo` property, you can just included whatever the properties that are present in all the responses and handle the rest of the properties using `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonAnySetter`. You can capture this in a map with key being your object name which is in this case `foo`. You need to have the following part in your parent node or whichever node that will encapsulates these optional properties.

```
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

Let me know if you need any further clarification!!

Comment: Clarify this. I'm going to be using my Bean class to extend the mixinClass but where am I placing the ObjectMapper code?

Comment: ObjectMapper goes with the file which is going to deserialize/serialize the content for you. It's not located in the POJO.

Comment: In further reading '@JsonProperty(value="foo", required=false)' are by default false, and by using the JsonIgnoreProperties it would remain false in which then I would need to alter all of the POJOs that we have in order to have them true and then use the JsonIgnoreProperties in order to alter the value. Is this accurate?............... And if that is the case then any other suggestions for how to approach this issues as we have hundreds of POJOs and the desire is to not have to go alter all of them.

Comment: I don't seem to follow. Why are intending to use this, `@JsonProperty(value="foo", required=false)` ? If you say `@JsonProperty(value="foo")` by default it is required

Comment: I was only trying to make a simple case in order to get a quick understanding of how to override the defaults. But things are a bit more complex here. Finally was able to see the output of everything that I'm working on here and the code we have has 10s thousands of lines of json that are output and hundreds of classes. So, I need to figure out how to go about defining required and non required properties with the least amount of impact on existing code.

Comment: Have all the required fields with `@JsonProperty`  and try to capture the optional properties with the `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@jsonAnySetter`. In this case you won't end up writing different POJO's for different requests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136777/discussion-between-coder-and-elijah).

Answer (score 1):

You can play wiht Mixins and the mapper:

```
public interface BarRequiredMixIn {
    @JsonProperty(value="bar", required=true)
    private BarProperty barProperty;
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// When you want that it is required
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(Bean.class, BarRequiredMixIn.class);
```

But I strongly recommend to avoid to use this kind of conditional restrictions with Jackson, since it is not designed for it, and it looks kind of confusing.

Comment: Bare with me on this. So, have Bean implement the interface and add the ObjectMapper code to my Bean class? I'm not clear on where that ObjectMapper code is to go or how to go about applying it to be able to alter the defaults of the Bean class.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you have given, setting the following in your POJO would be sufficient & Jackson would be able to figure out whether to deserialize it/not . All @JsonProperty are required by default, so with the code below, you would be able to achieve optional bar value in your Create/Update scenarios based on payload in the request

```
@JsonProperty(value="bar", required=false)
private Bar bar;
```